# Bind9 DNS reverse lookup fail

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind

Okay so I got a problem, that my reverse lookup fail on my bind9 dns

```
#nslookup 172.16.0.179
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

** server can't find 179.0.16.172.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN
```

Here is my reverse zone:

```
# nano /var/lib/bind/mosek.intranet.rev.zone

$ORIGIN .
$TTL 604800     ; 1 week
172.16.0.in-addr.arpa   IN SOA  braintree.mosek.intranet. admin.mosek.com. (
                            79         ; serial
                            604800     ; refresh (1 week)
                            86400      ; retry (1 day)
                            2419200    ; expire (4 weeks)
                            604800     ; minimum (1 week)
                            )
                    NS      braintree.mosek.intranet.
$ORIGIN 0.16.172.172.16.0.in-addr.arpa.
$TTL 3600       ; 1 hour
179                     PTR     harbinger.mosek.intranet.
```

The PTR entry is something bind9 autogenerated

and here is my /etc/bind/named.conf.local

```
//
// Do any local configuration here
//
include "/etc/bind/rndc.key";

zone "mosek.intranet" {
        type master;
        file "/var/lib/bind/mosek.intranet.zone";
        allow-update {key rndc-key; };
};

zone "172.16.0.in-addr.arpa"{
        type master;
        file "/var/lib/bind/mosek.intranet.rev.zone";
        allow-update {key rndc-key; };
};


// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";
```

as I see it, everything looks fine. what could cause the problem?

## **EDIT**

I got it working so here's the working config:

```
# cat /etc/bind/named.conf.local
//
// Do any local configuration here
//
include "/etc/bind/rndc.key";

zone "mosek.intranet" {
        type master;
        file "/var/lib/bind/mosek.intranet.zone";
        allow-update {key rndc-key; };
};

zone "0.16.172.in-addr.arpa"{
        type master;
        file "/var/lib/bind/mosek.intranet.rev.zone";
        allow-update {key rndc-key; };
};


// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";
```

.

```
# cat /var/lib/bind/mosek.intranet.rev.zone
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 604800     ; 1 week
0.16.172.in-addr.arpa   IN SOA  braintree.mosek.intranet. admin.mosek.com. (
                                79         ; serial
                                604800     ; refresh (1 week)
                                86400      ; retry (1 day)
                                2419200    ; expire (4 weeks)
                                604800     ; minimum (1 week)
                                )
                                NS      braintree.mosek.intranet.              $
$ORIGIN 0.16.172.in-addr.arpa.
$TTL 604800     ; 1 week
179                     PTR     harbinger.mosek.intranet.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When specifying PTR records using the `in-addr.arpa` domain, the least significant part of the network IP address should come before the remaining parts, i.e., the reverse of the usual way of specifying IP addresses in dot-decimal notation.

From [Wikipedia article on Reverse DNS lookups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup#IPv4_reverse_resolution)

> Reverse DNS lookups for IPv4 addresses use a reverse IN-ADDR entry in the
>   special domain in-addr.arpa. In this domain, an IPv4 address is represented
>   as a concatenated sequence of four decimal numbers, separated by dots, to
>   which is appended the second level domain suffix .in-addr.arpa. The four
>   decimal numbers are obtained by splitting the 32-bit IPv4 address into four
>   8-bit portions and converting each 8-bit portion into a decimal number.
>   These decimal numbers are then concatenated in the order: least significant
>   8-bit portion first (leftmost), most significant 8-bit portion last
>   (rightmost). It is important to note that this is the reverse order to the
>   usual dotted-decimal convention for writing IPv4 addresses in textual form.

In your case, `172.16.0.in-addr.arpa` should be re-written in **all** your BIND configuration files as `0.16.172.in-addr.arpa`. E.g., here’s how the zone file should look:

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 604800     ; 1 week
0.16.172.in-addr.arpa IN SOA  braintree.mosek.intranet. admin.mosek.com. (
                            79         ; serial
                            604800     ; refresh (1 week)
                            86400      ; retry (1 day)
                            2419200    ; expire (4 weeks)
                            604800     ; minimum (1 week)
                            )
                    NS      braintree.mosek.intranet.
$ORIGIN 0.16.172.in-addr.arpa
$TTL 3600       ; 1 hour
179                     PTR     harbinger.mosek.intranet
```

Comment: Hi I edited all the config files, but now I get a SERVFAIL instead of NXDOMAIN, when I try to reverse lookup

Comment: Thank you. There were a couple of extra errors too, but i got it working now. Thanks

Comment: Good stuff. It might be worth posting your working configuration as it may help other users who come across this question.